# Python ElementTree.parse() from file does not close the file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a xml file - kind of template to fill within the parameters and make a request (create some data).

I open this file with

```
tree = ET.parse(path_to_file)
```

and I make loop to get the xml from file, fill with the parameters and send a request. 
But after 2555 requests I get an error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'resources/cmr/skeletons/man/CreateLiveEvent.xml'
```

Is there a way to close file after ET.parse() opens it?

Thanks

Comment: You could try handling the file yourself and use [`fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring), see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Tried open file, and close after that. Did not make any difference. It seems problem not in ET.parse() but more in file handling?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrade your 2.7 installation. This supposedly was [fixed in issue #7334](http://bugs.python.org/issue7334), and was included in 2.7.3. It *does* look like there is a bug in the way the `cElementTree` implementation closes files however (e.g. it doesn't close them).

The alternative is to open the file yourself:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as xml_file:
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
```

and leave it to the `with` statement to close the file object. Open the file as *binary*; it is the job of the XML parser to handle line endings and encodings.

Comment: I tried this solution - and did not work :(

Code is:

    def getRoot(self, filePath):
        with open(filePath) as xml_file:
            tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        return root

Comment: @SergiiKozlov: Ah, possibly because ElementTree opens the file in binary mode (which is correct). If that still doesn't work, can you be more specific in how that doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry for late response. At that time it was possible to found a workaround but fighting with it again. My code is:   def getRoot(self, filePath):
        tree = ET.parse(filePath)
        root = tree.getroot()
        return root

And error message is:  IOError: [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: 'mypath/RegisterContent.xml'

which Im trying to open. 

thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you are following my advise there.

Comment: You right, sorry. I did wrong copy/paste. Here is correct one, but result still the same..

def getRoot(self, filePath):
        with open (filePath, "r") as myFile:
            tree = ET.parse(filePath)
            root = tree.getroot()
        myFile.close()
        return root

Comment: @SergiiKozlov: the `with` statement already closes the file, there is no need to call `close()` again. And you are sure and certain that you are not still using any other methods to open files anywhere else? What is the full traceback for example, it would have to be different from the case where you have ElementTree open the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could open the file yourself and close it:

```
source = open(path_to_file)
tree = ET.parse(source)
... do your work ...
source.close()
```

Comment: this will NOT always work, you need use `open(path_to_file,'rb')` in windows as mentioned by @Martijn Pieters. the reason is that xml file can have their encoding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`that is different then ASCII...it will result in parsing error `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a possible solution or work-around.

I was working on a large xml file, 240 Meg, just parsing and searching with no other file activity just to measure the time to search the data. The script did not even print any info. I had just one print('Done.') as the last statement at the end. When my script was done Python printed the "Done." and then hung for awhile while Python took care GC cleanup. I then saw a noticeable Python exit speed-improvement when I did:

```
def search(elem):
    """Recursive"""
    # check for lots of elements

tree = ET.parse(source)
root = tree.getroot() # a large and deep element
search(root) # time it

print('Deleting tree')
del tree

# root still usable after del tree.
# You can still process the in-memory root
# at this point but I suspect not tree.write().
process(root)

print('Deleting root')
del root  # not necessary but seemed to improve exit
print('Done')
```

Perhaps `del tree` closes the file. I do not know if this is true. I used cPython. I do not know if this is implementation independent.